# How to Implement a Full Screen button in Header with SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

In SAPUI5 demokit, I found there is a full screen button for chartContainer. Also in a explored example, the detail header has a full screen button as well. see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ChartContainer/preview

I would like to implement such a full screen button in header of my detail view. But How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You bind an event handler to the press event of the button and switch the mode of your SplitApp from ShowHideMode (default) to HideMode and vice versa to achieve that.